# How to release CGColorRef?

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I have the following code snippet

```
CGContextRef ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();  
CGColorRef color = CreateDeviceRGBColor(r,g,b,a);
CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(ctx, color);
```

When I run Build & Analyze in Xcode it gives me a "Potential leak ..." warning for `color`. How can I release it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `CFRelease(color);`. This works for all similar objects (e.g. all Core Foundation objects).

Answer (score 2):

mrrueg's answer will work, but it's slightly safer to use `CGColorRelease(color)` as this will not throw an error if color happens to be NULL. For reference, you should also use `CGColorRetain(color)` in circumstances where the color in question is not yet retained by the owner. This is not necessary in this instance, since CreateDeviceRGBColor returns a retained CGColorRef.